# Handling HTTP error codes in Install4j's "Download file" action

Tags: install4j

I'm working with Install4j and using its "Download file" action to download files via HTTP. However, I've encountered an issue when the file to be downloaded is not available, resulting in HTTP error codes like 404 (Not Found) or 403 (Forbidden). In these scenarios, instead of properly handling the error, the action downloads and saves the HTML error page to the designated file location, disregarding the actual HTTP status code. My observation is that the action seems to only explicitly handle redirection status codes, specifically 301 (Moved Permanently) and 302 (Found).

My question is: Is there a way to configure or extend the action to enhance its error management? I want to avoid downloading the error page content and instead handle errors more gracefully within my installer.

Any insights, workarounds, or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, for a 404 the download action fails for install4j 10.0.6 in my tests. Please start the installer from the command line with the arguments `-Dinstall4j.noWinInetConnection=true -Dinstall4j.showConnectError=true` . The actual status code of the response will be written to an error log next to the installer (the "Create log file for stderr output" property of the installer has to be selected for that)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I set `install4j.noWinInetConnection=true` and found that the action correctly handles 403 and 404 errors now. Do you know why the WinINet API might not handle these errors by default? Also, are there any side effects or limitations in using this setting for the launcher in a production environment?

Comment: For me, the native Windows connections do handle 404 (have not tried 403) so I don't know what the difference could be in your case. The only side effect of this parameter is that you will not get Windows proxy handling (like a proxy password dialog). Otherwise, the implementation is the same as would be used on macOS or Linux.